# Rails decorators, overriding a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm writing some decorators to override a Rails Engine as described [here](https://github.com/radar/forem#extending-classes). I'm trying to add a simple method to a class from the Engine, here's my code:

```
# app/decorators/models/my_engine/user_decorator.rb

MyEngine::User.class_eval do
  def self.find_by_name_or_mis_id str
    where("CONCAT(#{table_name}.firstname, ' ', #{table_name}.surname) LIKE CONCAT('%', :s, '%') OR mis_id = :s", { s: str })
  end
end
```

My app can't find the method, and in rails console I try to test it:

```
# rails c
MyEngine::User.find_by_name_or_mis_id "John"
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_name_or_mis_id' for #<Class:0x007fcb85a45580>
```

I can get it to work by doing `require '/models/my_engine/user_decorator'` at the console, why isn't rails picking up my decorators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well after quite a bit of rifling around, it turns out the don't seem to get autoloaded. What was required was (pinched from the [forem repo](https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/0fc9bae6d90cbf705f7c21284a8790168fc91da3/lib/forem/engine.rb), before they extracted it into [this gem](https://github.com/parndt/decorators)):

```
# MyEngine
# lib/my_engine/engine.rb

module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    config.to_prepare do
      Dir.glob(Rails.root + "app/decorators/**/*_decorator*.rb").each do |c|
        require_dependency(c)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'll raise a ticket on the docs so that they can include this info, seeing as they go in to some detail about decorators but don't explain how you actually load them (the assumption being that that's all handled for you).

**Update:** I did raise a [ticket](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10647), and the guides were updated accordingly.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for this, really helpful! Are you sure the guides got updated? I just stumbled upon the same issue, but did not find it mentioned here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers

Comment: By the way, am I right to assume this code goes in the engine itself? Isn'it a bit strange? I mean the engine should not need to know about that, should it?

Comment: So as not to hard-code slashes in the path: `Rails.root.join('app', 'decorators', '**', '*_decorator*.rb')`

Answer (score 2):

```
config.to_prepare do
  # Load application's model / class decorators
  Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
    Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bumping an old question.  I had a few problems with the decorators gem.  An alternative is [activesupport-decorators](https://github.com/pierre-pretorius/activesupport-decorators).

Answer (score 0):

For a flexible alternative that also works for Rails engines without the decorator `require_dependency` functionality built-in, consider mirroring the file path of the class you want to override and use require_dependency to require the original class before your customizations.

This technique doesn't use decorators. Instead it reopens the class in a file with the same name:

```
# File: app/models/my_engine/user.rb

# Load the original class definition from the engine:
require_dependency "#{MyEngine::Engine.root}/app/models/my_engine/user"

# Open class to modify it:
module MyEngine
  class User
    def self.find_by_name_or_mis_id(str)
      where("CONCAT(#{table_name}.firstname, ' ', #{table_name}.surname) LIKE CONCAT('%', :s, '%') OR mis_id = :s", { s: str })
    end
  end
end
```